# Библиотеки для работы с таблицами Excel для Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, существуют ли библиотеки для форматирования таблиц в excel (Ввод данных, заливка ячеек и т.)

Comment: выбирайте что нравится [вот здесь](https://www.python-excel.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas, openpixel, XlsxWriter. Все библиотеки разные и под разные задачи. Нужно по отдельности смотреть, что конкретно Вам нужно

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).